# TestRPC Accounts Locked

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testrpc

I'm having difficulty getting going with truffle and testrpc.

The steps I've taken are:

- Create a blank project and initialise with `truffle init`
- Start testrpc with `testrpc`

Trying `truffle migrate` or `truffle test` then gives me "

```
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:118:13)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
```

From what I've read this seems like an error with accounts being locked, but testrpc's documentation suggests that by default it will create 10 accounts which are unlocked - unless you specify `--secure`?

Comment: Try starting testrpc with $ testrpc -u 0 -u 1. Resolved?

Comment: @RobHitchens nope, same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had another instance of geth running, which truffle was trying to use instead of testrpc, and I hadn't deployed.

- Make sure testrpc is the only geth instance running
- Call `truffle deploy` before trying `truffle migrate` or `truffle test`

Answer (score 0):

You have prob with testrpc,just try to restart it after you deploy with truffle.
You can watch this tuto:
[truffle+MetaMask+testrpc](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fflYJh8Rtxc)